# How to find the function which is outputting Array

Tags: php, array, debug

I'm calling a plugin (Event Rocket) from a template and the output is mostly as expected but *seldom* the only thing that is displayed is "Array".

I have consulted the plugin's makers and they have no idea where it is coming from. They say something else may be filtering the output and giving the wrong output.

As this is a live website I'm not in the position to follow traditional Wordpress "debugging" steps (deactivating plugins, switching to a stock template - even less because the problem doesn't always manifest, so I'd have to let each step a significant amount of time to see if the problem disappears or not).

**What I'm hoping to learn is a programmatic method to catch the function where an Array is passed to the output.**

It is a PHP programming challenge on one hand, but Wordpress specific in the sense that I don't know which function to trace back and how. (Of course I'm interested in a merely different kind of solution too.)

Comment: There is no fast way to debug this. You have a function returning output or ouput from a function which is an array, and that array is being echoed to screen. Best way to debug this if you don't want to take down your site is to clone the site to a local test install and then debug it from there. Apart from this, I really don't have any other method to trace your issue but to work through each and every file on your live install if you don't want to debug it traditionally

Comment: You should be able to narrow down the location of the problem function by looking at the source of the page. Other than that, +1 to @PieterGoosen' s comment.

Comment: Thanks @pieter-goosen and s-ha-dum, I'll find out about a way to clone the site and debug there.
As for the programmatic approach, is there a distinct line of code in WP which is supposed to do the final output? I guess I could ob_start() it and catch the Array. Or I could just add a filter to the end of the chain with the same purpose and cross fingers...?